# How do you access wkhtmltopdf.exe file in Docker image?

Tags: python, docker, wkhtmltopdf

Here is my Dockerfile code:

```
FROM python:3.11.6

ADD /ReportGeneration/ .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python","BasicReports/Instagram/GenerateIGReport.py"]
```

The requirements.txt includes wkhtmltopdf. When I run the Docker image I get this error:

```
OSError: No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe"
If this file exists please check that this process can read it or you can pass path to it manually in method call, check README. Otherwise please install wkhtmltopdf - https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Installing-wkhtmltopdf
```

I have tried a few solutions, such as using wget and then using cp, but I have been unable to get something that works. It seems that the path specified is incorrect. What is the right path?

Answer (score 0):

The `wkhtmltopdf` Python Package is simply a wrapper for the `wkhtmltopdf` tool. You still need to install the executable on your image with :

```
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install wkhtmltopdf -y \
  && mv /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/local/bin/.
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Unfortunately this still returns: "OSError: No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe"

Comment: My mistake, forgot the missing `.exe` extension. Can you configure the path where the lib will look for the `wkhtmltopdf` executable ? Otherwise just add the missing .exe in the solution above (`/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe`)

Comment: That returns: ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update   && apt-get install wkhtmltopdf -y   && mv /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe /usr/local/bin/." did not complete successfully: exit code: 1  . Is it possible to use .exe in linux anyway?

Comment: Your replaced the wrong way, here is the full command : `mv /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe`. The executable is installed with the name `wkhtmltopdf`, `mv` will move it + rename it. Note that your post is marked as duplicated (see header), you might find additional information to help you in the original.